# Comparing two input fields

Tags: javascript, html

I have this function which i am using to compare two input fields. If the user enters the same number in both the text field. On submit there will be an error. Now i would like to know if there is a way to allow same number but not higher than or lower the value of the previous text box by 1. For example if user enters 5 in previous text box, the user can only input either 4, 5 or 6 in the other input field.Please give me some suggestions.

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
function Validate(objForm) {
var arrNames=new Array("text1", "text2");
var arrValues=new Array();
for (var i=0; i<arrNames.length; i++) {
var curValue = objForm.elements[arrNames[i]].value;
if (arrValues[curValue + 2]) {
alert("can't have duplicate!");
return false;
}
arrValues[curValue] = arrNames[i];
}
return true;
}
</script>
```

```
<form onsubmit="return Validate(this);">
<input type="text" name="text1" /><input type="text" name="text2" /><button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: What would you try? Also, I don't think your currenct function really checks for duplicate values.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A tidy way to do it which is easy to read:

```
var firstInput = document.getElementById("first").value;
var secondInput = document.getElementById("second").value;

if (firstInput === secondInput) {
    // do something here if inputs are same
} else if (firstInput > secondInput) {
    // do something if the first input is greater than the second
} else {
    // do something if the first input is less than the second
}
```

This allows you to use the values again after comparison as variables (firstInput), (secondInput).

Comment: Do something if Second is greather than Second? I think you mean if firstInput < secondInput or not equal?

Comment: @LmC I need to check `firstInput > secondInput` but it only validating for 1st digit only how to fix it? Ex: 59>9 here it only checking 5>9

Answer (score 3):

Here's a suggestion/hint

```
if (Math.abs(v1 - v2) <= 1) {
    alert("can't have duplicate!");
    return false;
}
```

And here's the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/su__/dtUUJ/) link, if you want to see the answer

Comment: @I pm I need to check firstInput > secondInput but it only validating for 1st digit only how to fix it?

Comment: You can do something like this in your validate function:
if (('' + a)[0] <= ('' + b[0])) {
  alert('invalid');
  return false;
}
Basically ('' + anyNumber)[0] will get you the first digit of a number.

Comment: @I pm Thank you for quick response..I didn't get you Once see my code here I wanna validate `firstInput > secondInput` I used this `document.getElementById('noOfWorkingComputers').value > document.getElementById('noOfComputers').value` but taking only validating for 1st digit only how to fix it? Ex: 59>9 here it only checking 5>9

Comment: here it's working fine for only single digit..If it checking like string even that single digit also not gonna be work naa?

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle (or something similar) link? So it would be easier to look at your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Give them both IDs.

Then use the

```
if(document.getElementById("first").value == document.getElementById("second").value){
    //they are the same, do stuff for the same
}else if(document.getElementById("first").value >= document.getElementById("second").value
    //first is more than second
}
```

and so on.